# Moving package between own repositories on bintray

Tags: bintray, jcenter

My organization has several maven repositories on bintray. Most of these repositories contain a single package of the same name as the repository.

These packages seem highly related and I would like to reorganize them by creating a single repository and moving all these packages into it.

What is the best way to move packages between own repositories given the following constraints:

- the package must remain available in the old repository as a link to the package in the new repository.
- some of packages are linked to jcenter and they must remain linked after the moving.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do this? I'm trying to find a way to do the very same thing.

Comment: @define, I haven't managed to do it yet, but I posted a response from the conversation with the support.

Answer (score 2):

I'll quote here a response from my conversation with JFrog support:

> Since it is not possible to link a package from one repository to another within the same organisation, the best option would be to move these packages to the new repository while maintaining the link to jcenter. This leave the old repositories empty and then you would be able to delete them entirely. It is not possible to retain a link from the old repository to the new one.
>
> Please notice that the move operation is an internal process and can only be done by us.

Unfortunately this approach doesn't satisfy my first requirement that the package must remain available for downloading from the old repository.

Comment: How can i checik this option in bintray? in my case, i have a repository plus the one package of my library.. but, i  understand that i can have ons single repo and multiple packages, could you comment sonething about that? :)